# How do i put unity game exe at startup

Tags: unity

As i have only unity build in exe format how can i put it to the startup of my window so that it run automatically when computer becomes start. Remember I don't want to put it manually is there any scripting ref available to do this or else auto solution?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I got your question right. You are trying to add your unity build to the autostart folder of windows?

Comment: This question came up in the review queue, and I'd like to edit it to improve the clarity rather than close it. To do that though, I'll need a bit of feedback from the author: "As I have only Unity build in exe format" does that mean you have just a compiled game from someone else, not your own source files?  Can you also describe the kind of "auto solution" you want? Are you envisioning an in-game dialog or menu that asks the player if they'd like to add the game to their startup programs? Or some kind of installer, or a utility script you run separately?

Comment: @DMGregory i have own game's build which i want to add in windows startup automatically (through code) as user first start player. Or the next option can be through setup installation as u suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can cause Windows to start an application at startup by adding a registry key to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run`. You should already have some such keys on your own system which you can view with the Windows registry editor (regedit.exe) as an example.

This is best done in the installer. Most installer toolkits allow to set registry keys during installation. But if you want to set that registry key from your game executable itself, check out the method [`Registry.SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a5t63w8(v=vs.110).aspx) from the .NET framework.